# Регулярное выражение для удаления числа из строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите.

Нужно из строки удалить определенное число. Например из строки

```
$str = '10 20 150 50 750 550 50';
```

удалить число 50, именно чтобы оно не затронуло 150, 750, 550.

пробую

```
preg_replace("/50[^\d]+/", NULL, $str );
```

но оно некорректно работает в начале и конце строки.
Совсем что то завис, помогите?

Comment: Добавь в начало и конец по пробелу. После замены - удали их.

Comment:  гениально. подождем, вдруг есть более изящное решение )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте один из следующих способов:

```
$str = '10 20 150 50 750 550 50';
$str = preg_replace('~\b50\b~', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('~(?<!\d)50(?!\d)~', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('~(?<!\S)50(?!\S)~', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('~(?<!\d\.|\d)50(?!\.?\d)~', '', $str);
```

Тут

- `\b50\b` - границы слова
- `(?<!\d)50(?!\d)` - цифровые границы
- `(?<!\S)50(?!\S)` - пробельные границы
- `(?<!\d\.|\d)50(?!\.?\d)` - это разновидность цифровых границ, найдёт `50`, но не `50.35`.

Comment: \b .. то что нужно!!!!